# pass text values without lose Enter(return)value jquery

Tags: jquery, string

i have a text area where i put my code and below div that shows a preview about the user are typing in the text area the problem it's that if the user press the enter key i lose the value. How can i pass this value???. Or am i doing wrong my method

**the html**

```
<textarea id="txtMessageFields"></textarea>
<div id="messagePreview"></div>
```

**the js**

```
$(document).ready(initialize);

function initialize(){

    $messageValues = $("#messagePreview");
    $("#txtMessageFields").keyup(previewData);
}

function previewData() {

    $messageValues.html('');
    var aux = this.value;
    $messageValues.append('<p>' + aux + '</p>');
}
```

[See my code run](http://jsfiddle.net/kJzDw/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did small change to your code is this what you need?

```
function previewData() {

    $messageValues.html('');
    var aux = this.value.replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g,'<br>');
    $messageValues.append('<p>' + aux + '</p>');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hfV7y/

Comment: hi and thank's for asking that's all??. Only replacing all the cases with a regular expression i can remove and set the values that i want??

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you mean by losing the value?
Does the whole code preview disappear? You jsfiddle link has some other code in.

I ran your code in jsfiddle and it works aside the fac that when you press Enter, the preview code is still on one line.
You should see what key is pressed whenever the keyup event is triggered and whenever the key is Enter just append a `<br>` to your preview div's content.

See here how to get the keycode: http://api.jquery.com/keyup/